# Risk neutral price in discounted vs original market

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

Suppose $X=(X^0,\dots, X^n)$ is a continuous time financial market on $[0,T]$ with $X^1,\dots, X^n$ risky assets and $X^0$ the bank account, and the source of randomness is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t) P)$ where the filtration is the natural filtration of the brownian motion, and $X$ is an $n+1$-dimensional vector Ito-process

Let $Q$ be an equivalent local martingale measure. Suppose $H$ is a $Q$-integrable european contingent claim, where $H=h(X^1_T,\dots, X^n_T)$ where $h$ is smooth.
The risk-neutral price of $H$ at time $t$ w.r.t to $Q$ is
$$
\pi_t := X^0_t E^Q\left(H/X_T^0|\mathcal{F}_t\right).$$

Now consider the discounted market $\bar{X}$. How is $\pi_t$ related to $\bar{\pi}_t$ where $\bar{\pi}_t$ is the risk-neutral price of the claim $\bar{H}:=h(\bar{X}^1,\dots,\bar{X}^n)$ w.r.t to $Q$ in the discounted market, i.e.
$$
\bar{\pi}_t = \bar{X}^0_t E^Q\left(\bar{H}/\bar{X}_T^0|\mathcal{F}_t\right) = E^Q(\bar{H}|\mathcal{F}_t)?
$$

If $h$ is a linear form, this is easy as $\bar{H} = H/X^0_T$. What can be said if $h$ is non-linear? What, if furthermore $X^0$ is deterministic?

I.e., how can the risk-neutral price of a claim given by a formula of the final asset-prices be computed by looking at the claim given by the same formula in the discounted market?

Comment: 1) Why do you substitute discounted prices into $h$? 2) Isn't $\bar X^0 \equiv 1$?

Comment: @zhoraster Yes $\bar{X}^0=1$. I am given a concrete drift vector and volatility matrix for the discounted market, and am told nothing about the original market but that the risk rate was deterministic. Then I am asked to compute the risk-neutral price of a claim that is expressed in terms of asset prices of the original market.
So doing the standard computations (computing ELMM) I arrive fully prepared to compute the risk neutral price of claims expressed in terms of the asset prices of the discounted market.

Comment: But, the original claim was non-linearily expressed in terms of the original asset prices...

Comment: @zhoraster I think the question could be rephrased to how to systematically use the martingale property under the EMM of the discounted asset prices for claims that are non-linearily expressed in terms of the original asset prices... E.g., how would I compute the price of $H=\exp(X^1_T + X^2_T)$ starting from a model of the discounted market?

Comment: I do not understand that. The derivatives are written on original assets, not on the discounted ones. Discounting is a kind of abstraction: you can actually discount by any of the assets (if it is a.s. positive), and you would get the same non-arbitrage prices. So plugging discouted values into payoff functions makes little sense to me.

Comment: Take e.g. a vanilla call: it allows to buy an asset for a strike price $K$, this corresponds to payoff $C = (X^i_T - K)_+$, which is just money equivalent of the call. But what is $\bar C = (\bar X^i_T - K)_+$? I'm not saying you can't do that. But, naturally, there is no reason to expect the prices of $C$ and $\bar C$ to be related.

Comment: @zhoraster But is there really no relation between $C$ when interpreted in the original market (i.e. discounted after computation) and $\bar{C}$ when interpreted in the discounted market (i.e. left as is)?

Comment: We have $(X^0_tE(X^i_T/X^0_T|\mathcal{F}_t))/X^0_t=\bar{X}^i_t = \bar{X}^0_tE(\bar{X}^i_T/\bar{X}^0_T|\mathcal{F}_t)$, which, if $K=0$ for $C$ corresponds to what I meant: There is relationship between $C$ and $\bar{C}$ (their prices can be retreived from each other by discounting after computation), but just because the claim is a linear form of the final asset prices. What if the formula is non-linear? Or, how do I compute the price of $exp(X^1_T + X^2_T)$ knowing the price of the claim $exp(Y^1_T + Y^2_T)$ of a market $Y$ that just so happens to be the discounted market $\bar{X}$ of $X$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104033/discussion-between-zhoraster-and-ramen).